# Declining flags and justification

Tags: discussion

It'd be REALLY nice if a comment could be left as to why it was 'denied', as it would save me and everyone else the feeling of frustration and clogging up meta meta asking 'Why was my flag declined'?

Comment: For the *other* flag, moderators already add comments when they feel it necessary.

Answer (score 9):

We can't leave decline reasons on comment flags, nor should we really be wasting time doing so.

If you're talking about your comment flag to convert it into an answer, moderators do not have any tool to convert comments into an answer. All we would do is post it as a community wiki answer, but you are perfectly capable of posting an answer yourself.

Comment: I think a community wiki answer is better than questioner / someone else copying it as it's a response rather than no response. And, I like how this answer has two upvotes yet my question has two downvotes!

Comment: @user3791372 So make yours community wiki? Why does a moderator need to do it? Any user can mark their own answer as community wiki.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that...Ah, i see it now, it's that tiny, tiny box, with grey text against a white background in an area my eyes never need to fall on to type an answer and neither to press the 'post your answer' button. Maybe it should be moved to a more prominent area?

Comment: @user3791372: Nope, it should not be moved to a more prominent place: CW is only for special cases like this, nearly always CW would be wrong.